# App Engine Http Servlet request per user

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, servlets

How to restrict single thread execution per user in App Engine Java `HttpServlet` get request?

Java `synchronized` call will synchronize across all thread access, whereas I want to do a synchronization per user.

The second execution call from the user can be allowed after the completion of the first call etc.

Do I need to go for `memcache` kind of approach or there is a inbuilt mechanism available?

Comment: Have a collection of synchronization objects per user and do synchronization on this objects?